# How to determine whether a function in a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Could you help me for my project question? I am not sure how can I handle it. Any suggestion would be okay for me, thanks in advance.

> For what values of $k$, if any, is the vector $(k^2, -3k, -2) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ in the span of
>   $$
> \left\{(1,2,3),~(0,1,1,),~ (1,3,4) \right\}
> $$?

Comment: I would approach it by taking coefficients $s, t, u$ for the three vectors ($\vec{v}_i$) mentioned and take a look at
$$
s \vec{v}_1 + t \vec{v}_2 +  u \vec{v}_3 = (k^2, -3k, -2)
$$
This is an equation for $s, t, u$ and you can form a system of equations from it ...

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I will be providing you hints to solve it :

1) $span\left\{(1,2,3),~(0,1,1),~ (1,3,4) \right\}=
span\left\{(1,2,3),~(0,1,1) \right\}$.

2) $(k^2,-3k,-2)$ lies in $span\left\{(1,2,3),~(0,1,1) \right\}$ iff the three vectors here are linearly dependent.

3) Above three vectors are linearly dependent iff the matrix created by them has determinant zero.

Comment: Thank you, sir or miss. What I understood from your hints I can manipulate the basis vectors by multiplying them with scalars and adding them. So, taking the basis vectors (1,2,3) and (0,1,1) to get (k^2,-3k,-2), I multiplied the first one with k^2 and second one with -(2k^2 + 3) to get x and y values then I solved the equation for z value and found k can be either 2 or 1. So is my technique okay? Thanks in, advance. You helped me a lot even conquering my fear towards this question.

Comment: Yes you have solved it correctly. Cheers.

Comment: OMG,  didn't believed that I could do it. You cannot imagine how much you've helped me, I'm very much grateful to you thanks.